# how to disable img tag on angular2? [disabled]="true" not working

Tags: angular, ionic2

My code is:

`<ion-card style="width:20%; height: 20%" #btnAnswer [id]="i" *ngFor="let answer of pageButtons.answers;  let i=index" [style.background]="answer.color" (click)="answerClicked(i)" >
<img src="assets/img/{{answer.name}}.png" />`
But i can't disable img element.

Comment: why do you want to disable an image? it has no function that you can disable. What do you expect to happen? go hidden or?

Comment: i can clicking to image at now. but i don't want to be clicked after the query. hide is not suitable for me

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to disable an image. It doesn't make sense.

What you want, is to make sure the user can't trigger another request after clicking on the image so you should just add a property to your answer object, let's call it `clicked`.

And then, in your `answerClicked` method do something like that :

```
private answerClicked(answer: any, index: number) {
  if (answer.clicked) return;

  // this code will only be reached if the answer was not already clicked
  answer.clicked = true;

  // your previous code
}
```

Also, I'd like to point out that passing the index doesn't seem to be a good idea. You should just pass the `answer` object.